# Prime with highest power that divides $N$

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, prime-factorization

Given a natural number $n$, how can I find the prime $p$ with highest power $e$ in the prime factorization of $n$.
E.g: $n=12=2^2.3$
$\therefore p=2 \ \ and\ \ e=2. $
E.g 2: 
$n=450=5^2 * 3^2 * 2^1$ So the prime with highest power is 3 or 5. We can print any of them as a valid answer.
I can prime factorize a number in $O(logn)$ for $n<10^6$. How shall I solve this problem for $n$ upto $10^{12}$.

Comment: Suggestion for some cases: Check if the number is a perfect square (manageable in $O(n)$)  [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_factor). You can then factorize a much smaller number.

Comment: So what is $p$ if $n=450$?

Comment: @Henry, Any of 3 or 5 will work for 450.

Comment: Cast out prime factors $p<10^6$. Anything that remains must be a prime.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen that will still be $O(\sqrt{n})$.

Comment: So how fast can you prime factorise $n$ for $10^6 \le n \le 10^{12}$?

Comment: Not to be pessimistic, but why do you think this is solvable?

Comment: Since $n$ is bounded, you can combine Hagen von Eitzens answer with parallel programming. Basically divide the range $\sqrt n$ with the available processors. Asymptotic runtime remains unchanged but your constants become low.

Comment: @maverick I suppose you are interested in a solution working for e.g. a coding competition, not the theoretical limit as $n\to\infty$. So I stand by my suggestion: The primes up to $10^6$ are quickly generated with a sieve (and can be reused for multiple inputs). As a bonus, if you have found some $q^e\mid N$ with $e\ge1$, then you may possibly stop early, namely when the next tested $p^{e+1}$ exceeds the unfactored remainder. -- Also note that you *must* find and print a prime factor of $N$, so *some* partial factorization is unavoidable.

Answer (score -1):

Since $n$ is bounded, this is a great way to use a **look up table**.

As there are [approximately](http://primes.utm.edu/howmany.html/)

$$\pi(n) \approx \frac{n}{\ln(n)}$$

which is your case equals only $\frac{10^6}{\ln(10^6)}\approx78498$
possible prime factors.
This should be the fastest approach.

Comment: Actually, $\pi(10^6)=78498$. But that is still doable.